# Failed Selenium IDE tests with WebDriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am currently using Selenium IDE for testing. I need to test on other browsers besides Firefox, so I decided to go with Internet Explorer.

I downloaded selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar file and IEDriverServer_Win32_2.44.0.exe and successfully am able to run my Selenium IDE tests on Internet Explorer.

However, the tests completely fail on IE. Every other command or test on IDE fails in IE. Each time IE cannot find links and ids of elements on the page. Yet, my IDE tests passes perfectly on Firefox.

Are there any reasons why IDE tets would pass successfully on Firefox but pass in such a miserable fashion in Explorer?

Also, I'm using IE version 8.

Thank you.

Here is the Log report showing all the errors. As you can see, it cannot find the element on the fifth line. But the same script works fine in Firefox. Why would it be unable to find the elements in IE but CAN in Firefox?

```
[info] Playing test case 2.8 Manage Subjects (SBJ)
[info] Executing: |open | https://company's URL here | |
[info] Executing: |type | id=ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_txtUserName | username |
[info] Executing: |type | id=ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_txtPassword | password |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | id=ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_pbSubmit | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | id=ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_AdminLinkButton | |
[error] Element id=ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_AdminLinkButton not found
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=Pharma Architect | |
[error] Element link=Pharma Architect not found
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait |
```

Comment: please provide a sample of the errors.

Comment: There are definitely commands that fail in webdriver that work fine in the IDE. This might not be specific to IE.

Comment: but isn't this the most basic of commands... clickAndWait ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not positive what I meant by that...
But it IS a chance that the html DOM is different in IE than firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I do not run test on IDE but my WebDriver tests run fine on the version of IE11 (maybe update your browser) I have shown.  I've found that anything newer than this I have problems with.

[image]